# QR Code coming out too blurry on Android 11

Tags: android, qr-code, android-7.0-nougat, android-11

I built an Android app that prints out QR codes in 2018 using a 3rd party (Dothantech's LPAPI) SDK.
It was run on Android 7 tablets from RCA without any issues.

Recently, the tablets were upgraded to Android 11 ones from Samsung. Although my app code wasn't changed (i.e. same APK), the QR codes are now coming out a lot more blurry and are not readable by QR code scanners. Since none of the app / SDK code changed, I think this must be an Android 7 vs 11 issue. Does anyone have any tips?

[image]

In the pictures above, the QR code from the left is printed with the Android 7 device. The one on the right is printed with the Android 11 device and is unreadable. The same exact APK is used for both.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted the company that created the SDK (support@dothantech.com) - they sent a new SDK and now the problem is fixed!